# Assigning comma separated lines to a variable

Tags: make

(Is it possible/How) to assign comma separated lines to a variable in make file?

```
var1=name,name2,
name3,name4.....
```

For space separated I just have use \
like this

```
var = name1 name2 \
name3 name4
```

Answer (score 0):

[I suppose that you want to write a long list of words separated by comma on multiple lines, the same as with space separated word lists; for a simple assignment, you can just do it with `var = a,b,c`]

I don't think that's possible with the standard `make`; with GNU make (the default on linux), you can use the `subst()` function for that:

```
$ cat Makefile
list = first,second,\
    third,fourth,\
    fifth,sixth

e :=
c := ,
list := $(subst $c $e,$c,$(list))

list:; echo $(list)
$ make
echo first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth
first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth
```

If you're using GNU make a better approach would be to the define the list as space-separated, and transform it to comma-separated later on:

```
$ cat Makefile
words = first     second \
        third     fourth \
        fifth     sixth

e :=
c := ,
clist = $(subst $e $e,$c,$(strip $1))

words:; echo $(call clist,$(words))

$ make
echo first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth
first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth
```